# Get values from database to textbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms, textbox

I have a WinForm that have a DataGridView and a ComboBox, allowing users to select a subject (from the database).

> ```
>   cbxSubject.DataSource = dsSched.Tables["Schedules"];
>   cbxSubject.DisplayMember = "Subject";
>   ...
> ```

The DataGridView looks something like this: http://i45.tinypic.com/18gmmu.png I added the DataGridView since I don't know any other way how to get those values from the database. I used a code, something like this, to get the values:

> TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

But then I realized that it won't work anymore if there are more than 2 subjects to choose from, because the code is set to get the value on the 3rd row and the 1st cell. So even when the user changed subject, the output value (w/c are then displayed in a TextBox) will still be the same. Are there any other ways to get those values? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Just asking... is this homework?

Comment: You should tag it so ("homework")... and damn kid, there are actually a lot of questions embedded in your post. Please, try to break it down to more short/simple questions. Also, include what is working already - I couldn't gather that from your post. Finally, I want help out, so please give me more details of how the program is supposed to work.

Comment: @BrunoBrant Oh, why? My only question is how to insert those values stored in the database to the textbox in the form.

Comment: I mean, how do I get the value? Like, the PrimaryKey or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comboxbox this way

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn subjectsCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
subjectsCombo.DataPropertyName = "SubjectID";
subjectsCombo.HeaderText = "Subjects";


subjectsCombo.DataSource = dsSched.Tables["Subjects"];
subjectsCombo.ValueMember = "SubjectID";
subjectsCombo.DisplayMember = "SubjectText";

cbxSubject.Columns.Add(subjectsCombo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to get some of your doubts out of the way:

> I added the DataGridView since I don't know any other way how to get
>   those values from the database

You already have a `DataSet` called "dsSched" filled with database values. So, no, you don't need the `DataGridView`. Just fill whatever you want directly from the DataSet:

```
string data = dsSched.Tables["Schedules"].Rows[3].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

> then I realized that it won't work anymore if there are more than
>   2 subjects to choose from, because the code is set to get the value on
>   the 3rd row and the 1st cell.

Well, I'm not sure **where** you are running that piece of code (`TextBox1.Text = Data...`), but if you are running it on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DataGridView`, then you should get data from the exact row that the user selected (or something, again, I did not understood what you are trying to do).

One thing that I suspect is that you are under the impression that the code:

```
TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

...is binding the textbox to the value in the row / cell. That's not how this works - the value is retrieved once when the code is run, and then again whenever the code is run  again. So you should make sure the code is run when you have to get this value.

---

**EDIT:**

> I mean, how do I get the value? Like, the PrimaryKey or something?

That's the question! I'm sorry, I was probably deviating. Just set the `[ValueMember][1]` to the string that describes the value column of the dataset.

cbxSubject.ValueMember = "Schedule ID";

Than you access it using `[SelectedValue][2]`, like:

```
int selValue = (int)(cbxSubject.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: It's like this, the user has to choose his subject from the combobox. Which could be one or more. This code **dsSched.Tables["Schedules"].Rows[3].Cells[1]...** works fine, and it displays the value of the cell in the textbox. However, if there are more than two subjects to choose from, the value in the textbox won't change anymore because the code is set to only get the row[3],cells[1]. Meaning, the code itself has to be changed.

Comment: Some questions: 1) which method is running the *dsSched.Tables["Schedules"].Rows[3].Cells[1]*?
2) What textbox is "TextBox1" in your picture?

Comment: No, removed it already. Right now I'm trying to use a datatable to fetch only one row so maybe it'll be possible to use the code again. Yeah all of those textbox should have values in them. Like the description..etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you DONT use constants.  Rather that using 3 and 1, you need to write some code to find `R` and `C` from what the user selects.  It should be event driven and you need to re-set the text box on change.  I'm assuming you are using an on-change event, but you haven't actually given us that information yet.

here's some pseudocode to get where im going with this

```
public DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, ChangedEventArgs e)
{//this might not be the right event, I'll leave it up to you to do your own homework
    int R = //Get the current Selected Row;
    int C = //Get the current Selected Cell/column;

    TextBox1.Text = dsSched.Tables["Schedules"].Rows[R].Cells[C];

    ///OR YOU COULD DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS

    TextBox1.Text = ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
}

//Please note, this is only pseudocode, I dont like doing peoples homework for them.
```

This should give you a more generic idea/algorithm that you would need.  Keeping in mind that this might not even be the best way to go about doing this, but Its what I would recommend based solely on the information provided to us thus far.  btw, what have you tried? and can you give us some larger code examples, there might be a rather more simple mistake being made that you haven't shown us so we cant tell you about it :-)

Considering that you still haven't actually asked the correct question, because we dont know WHY you are trying to do what you have stated you are doing, I can't get any more specific than this.  GIGO, you have to ask the right question in order to get the right answer.

Comment: Oh, let's say the user selected a row, would it be possible to select a column from that row? Like the, description for example. (Refer to the picture)

Comment: Yes...use a different cell, or use the columns collection of the row object.